# Modx: getResources - sort by id ascending/descending?

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, getresource

I want to try and order my resources by ID in ascending order.

Annoyingly, the documentation doesn't mention this though I am sure its possible.

Currently I have:

```
&sortby=`id`
```

Would anyone know the correct way to order by ascending or descending?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you're reading the [correct documentation](http://rtfm.modx.com/display/ADDON/getResources#getResources-SelectionProperties)?

You should be able to use

```
[[getResources? &sortby=`id` &sortdir=`ASC` ...
```

Comment: ah right - you are correct. I should have looked harder. I assumed it would have been mentioned in the sortby section